# How to simulate BJT cut-off in SPICE

Tags: current, bjt, npn, spice

In BJTs, when applying the parameter of collector and base current cut-offs, everything below a given cut-off current gets floored to 0mA, right?

So say if we have a configuration with good voltages (say 5V-24V range inputs and supply), but extremely high resistors at base and collector. Even if we measure voltages at the same range at the NPN terminals, if we were to measure the collector side's voltage (say Common emitter or Common gate configuration), we'd see a point that if the voltage at the base is:

**nearly** 0V: 
(with Common Emitter) collector output will ceil to supply

**nearly** equal to supply:
(with Common Gate) collector output will floor to ground

This should not be because the input has fallen below V_be_sat and we are dealing with **small signals**, but because the cut-off happens. Yet I don't see this happening with either Common configuration.

How do I implement this effect as this doesn't even seem to be simulated in SPICE? Is this even worth considering?

I was just asking because with my designs with BJT, I would use large resistors (sometimes even to 100Meg Ohms). I've always thought it was alright if most of the signal are 20 times above the cut-off currents. But I just realized that the smaller the ratio of the cut-off currents to most of the current is, the more pronounced is the effect of output being ceiled and floored is. So maybe that's why people don't use such large valued-resistors.

**EDIT:**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Now, for the sake of argument the collector current cut-off is 10uA (a pretty bad component, but, like I said for the sake of argument) then everything below it (around the lowest peak of the current plot) will be floored. So that means at that time frame, the collector voltage (the V_OUT) will bump sharply to the supply of 16V, then back down.

So what we'll be seeing is not clipping, but rather "square bumps".

I guess it would help if I edited the last 2 pics, but sorry, it's really late and I'd now rather hit the sack.

**EDIT:**

Due to responders not understanding what was being communicated, I have here an addendum to further explain things. Also, resetting my progress on the edit before I had the time to press "Save Edit" was really classy for you guys.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff0GI3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are the edited plots if we were to apply current cut-offs. I've also plotted the base and emitter voltages so we know that the terminals (theoretically) had good voltages, if this still means anything as we really can't demonstrate current cut-offs in SPICE.

[image]
[image]

Here's what it'd look like if we don't have the degeneration.
[image]
[image]
Hard to spot, isn't it??

Comment: A schematic of the circuit you're simulating would help make it clear what you're talking about.

Comment: In general, our back of the envelope models (like current goes to 0 when Vbe is below 0.6 V) are just rough approximations and the SPICE model is much more accurate. You may be seeing leakage effects that SPICE includes but aren't practical to calculate by paper-and-pencil. But again, without a schematic I'm not really sure what you're simulating.

Comment: Does V1 have a DC component? What is it's value? What is the amplitude of the V1 AC signal?

Comment: It obviously does. That's why it's not hitting negative. I made it about 3.8V.

Comment: This question has turned into a trainwreck. It's now completely unclear to me what you actually want to know. One thing is for sure though, and that is that you can't just edit your graphs in paint, and then ask us why SPICE doesn't draw whatever you have manually drawn. Are you having a problem where SPICE does not match your physical circuit? If so, then please show us _oscilloscope traces_ and a _real_ circuit diagram. If, on the other hand, you have a problem understanding how transistors work, you should probably stop blaming SPICE, or the people trying to answer the question.

Comment: So you say. but anybody that's competent enough to be doing basic  electronics (say somebody like me) should be able to follow everything here. Also the evolution of the discussion is in no way harder to follow than reading through an ordinary forum thread from any other site.

Comment: @Majin_Boo Stackexchange is _not_ a forum, though. That's the reason it's so useful. Forums are full of discussions to and from, with the questions changing half-way through. That's besides the point though. I still think you fail to demonstrate why you believe this "cutoff" exists. BJT aren't simply current-controlled devices, that's just an (over?)simplification. If you can demonstrate that it actually exists, I'm sure you will get some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question in your post, no. A BJT is in cuttoff when the voltage between the base and emitter is below a certain threshold. There is no current cutoff. A large R2 in this configuration will never cause cuttoff to happen. You don't have a spice problem, you have an understanding problem.

To answer your title, make the voltage between the base and the emitter go below      ~0.7V and the BJT will be in the cuttoff state.

Comment: Oh the R2. That was just for degeneration, else we'll just see swinging from rail to rail.

Comment: Alright, you know what?? I should've made sure I made myself clear with the schematic and actually showed the correct pics. I was in a hurry to finish up. I'm doing the edit now.

Comment: @Majin_Boo, Your schematic doesn't invalidate PetEEy's answer. (They understood your question much better than I did). Cut-off isn't controlled by collector current, it's controlled by the b-e voltage. Since b-e voltage never drops below ~0.6 V in your circuit, the BJT never goes into cut-off.  If you saw a spec in a datasheet for "collector cut-off current" that's probably telling you the maximum leakage current as a result of being in cut-off, not a current limit that controls when cut-off happens.